# Loading multiple google interstitial ads makes app crash

Tags: swift, admob

I am loading over 30 interstitial ads and my app crashes due to a memory issue. I tried loading them in the viewDidAppear and still had the same issue. I've seen many apps with tons of interstitial ads. How can I load many ads without getting a memory issue?

```
func loadAds(){
    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "")

    let req = GADRequest()
    interstitial.loadRequest(req)

    interstitial2 = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "")

    let reqq = GADRequest()
    interstitial2.loadRequest(reqq)

    interstitial3 = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "")

    /// 30 more interstitial ads
}
```

Message from my debugger...
"spritekitGame[2908:5497] Received memory warning.
Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you go about using AdMob's interstitials. You should only be creating one `var` to store your interstitial in.

Create the interstitial and request an ad. Once you've presented the ad and the ad has been dismissed you request another ad. Listen to its delegate methods to find out when its been dismissed.

For example:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds // Import AdMob

class ViewController: UIViewController, GADInterstitialDelegate { // Delegate

    // Create variable
    var myInterstitial: GADInterstitial!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadAd() // Load the ad
    }

    func loadAd() {
        myInterstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "your_admob_id") // Create ad
        myInterstitial.delegate = self // Set delegate
        myInterstitial.loadRequest(GADRequest()) // Request ad
    }

    func showAd() { // Call this func when you want to show an ad
        if myInterstitial.isReady { // Check to see if interstitial has an ad and is ready to be displayed
            myInterstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self) // Present the ad
        }
        else {
            print("Ad not ready")
        }
    }

    func interstitialDidDismissScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
        // The ad has been dismissed from the screen by the user
        // Request a new ad for the next time you want to show one
        loadAd() // Load a new ad
    }
```

For more information refer to Google's docs, [AdMob for iOS](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial#prerequisites).

Comment: how do i keep loading the ads though, like every interstitial id?

Comment: @BOB You should only have one interstitial id.

Comment: but I can't load it more than once. thats what it says on googles documentation

Comment: @BOB They're stating you can't use the same **object** more than once. When `loadAd()` is called in `interstitialDidDismissScreen` we are creating a brand new `GADInterstitial` with `myInterstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "your_admob_id")`.

Comment: thanks for elaborating I understand how this works with admit now.