# GADInterstitial error

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I get an error in this line `ad.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-1469592343938512/3581855984"` and I don't know how I can fix it.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var BannerView: GADBannerView!

var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.interstitial = self.createAndLoadAD()

    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
    BannerView.delegate = self
    BannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-1469592343938512/2613153588"
    BannerView.rootViewController = self
    BannerView.loadRequest(request)
}

func createAndLoadAD() -> GADInterstitial{

    var ad = GADInterstitial()
    ad.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-1469592343938512/3581855984"

    var request = GADRequest()

    request.testDevices = ["ca-app-pub-1469592343938512/3581855984"]

    ad.loadRequest(request)
    return ad
}

@IBAction func ADButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    if (self.interstitial.isReady) {
        self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
        self.interstitial = self.createAndLoadAD()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: *"I get an error in this line"*. What is the error?

Comment: `request.testDevices = ["ca-app-pub-1469592343938512/3581855984"]` this is not right.

Comment: Check this example. Each line is commented out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36389999/2108547

Comment: I get two errors when I use your linked sample

Answer (score 0):

**Remove the line createAndLoadAD() inside of ADButton.** 
= The recommended lifecycle for a GADInterstitial is to preload it when the app starts , which you have done correctly in viewdidload

Correct code is

```
if interstitial.isReady {
    interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
  } else {
    print("Ad wasn't ready")
  }
```

Refer https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/interstitial and https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/tree/master/Swift/admob/InterstitialExample/InterstitialExample for complete example.

If this doesn't solve your problem. kindly share your logs as well

Comment: syntax is not correct. refer to link given by Daniel